# Multiple logical tests in If function

Tags: excel

In this formula, an "if" function used to make a list of customer who fulfill specific conditions.

```
{=INDEX('Sales Data'!$B:$B,MATCH(0,IF(('Sales Data'!$G:$G="shoes")*('Sales Data'!$H:$H="reebok"),COUNTIFS($A$11:A11,'Sales Data'!$B:$B),""),0)}
```

I want to understand that what is the function of "*" in "if" function in logical test area.

Comment: 1) ask your superior directly for explanations; 2) research **array formula** online if you know little about it; 3) use **F9 key** to debug each component of the function see what they returns; 4) research the use of TRUE and FALSE in formula calculations. If you still have question, happy to elaborate.

Comment: Sir, Your suggestion is also helpful Thanks to you for replying my Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is based on the rule:

```
True * True = 1
True * False = 0
False * False = 0
```

You boss' formula `('Sales Data'!$G:$G="shoes")*('Sales Data'!$H:$H="reebok")`, which means,for example `{True, False, True,...,True}*{True, False, False,...,True}`,
will return a array contains 0 or 1s, which is array like `{1, 0, 0,...,1}`.

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot

It is using simple multiplication function like ($G:$G=shoes)=1 if true & ($H:$H=reebok) = 1 if true hence it comes (1*1=1)